# How to add annoyed nuance when speaking?

Tags: grammar, words, particles

Say someone is continuously telling me I’m doing something wrong whilst I’m trying my best.
Something I would say in English would be “Ok/Well tell me then, what should I do?!”
Which I think translates to “じゃあ教えて...何するの？“
But 教えて doesn’t feel like it carries that annoyed nuance of “Well tell me then”. So are there any particles or phrases that fulfill that purpose?
Also I’m not sure if “何するの？” is the correct grammar for “what should I do?”
If someone could verify that’d be great too. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about...

「じゃあ、どうすりゃいいんだよ？教えろよ！」

「じゃあ、どうしろってんだよ？言ってみろよ！」

↑These both sound masculine. Females might say something like...

「じゃあ、どうすりゃいいのよ？教えてよ！」

「じゃあ、どうしろってのよ？言ってみなさいよ！」